# Electron app name doesn't change

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, node-modules

i'm packaging my application using electron-packager but isn't changing its name, and still display "Electron".

it's supposed to use the `productName` in my `package.json` but it doesn't change.

even if i made an installer, the name of the app installed, shortcut and process still is `Electron`

i've read that maybe the problem is `electron-prebuilt` but i didn't have it as a dependency on my project.

Any idea what is wrong?

**Edit:**

reading more on the documentation of `electron-packager` there's an options especially to windows. but when i use them throws me an error:

```
Fatal error: Unable to commit changes
undefined
```

the first time i used them was "working" good packaging my app, but still displaying wrong the appname

```
electron-packager ./ --platform=win32 --arch=ia32 --overwrite=true --appname="TierraDesktop" --version-string.ProductName="TierraDesktop" --version-string=InternalName="TierraDesktop" --version-string.CompanyName="Cosmica" --version-string.FileDescription="Sistema de gestion comercial" --version-string.OriginalFilename="TierraDesktop"
```

before was working with `--version-string.ProductName` but now even with it still throws that error.

here i'll leave you my `packager.json` that's on the root of my project

```
{
"name": "TierraDesktop",
"productName": "TierraDesktop",
"version": "2.0.5",
"description": "Aplicacion de escritorio tierra de colores",
"main": "main.js",
"scripts": {
    "start": "electron main.js"
},
"repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/xxxx/xxxxx.git"
},
"author": "xxxxx",
"devDependencies": {
    "debug-menu": "^0.4.0",
    "electron-winstaller": "^2.3.3"
},
"dependencies": {
    "electron-json-storage": "^2.0.0"
}
}
```

[image: Executable]

[image: Process name]

[image: Application name]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok after trying and researching i've decided to package my application via programmatic API

with this script i can achieve all what i want. hope this help someone with the same problem.

```
var packager = require('electron-packager');
var options = {
    'arch': 'ia32',
    'platform': 'win32',
    'dir': './',
    'app-copyright': 'Paulo Galdo',
    'app-version': '2.0.5',
    'asar': true,
    'icon': './app.ico',
    'name': 'TierraDesktop',
    'ignore': ['./releases', './.git'],
    'out': './releases',
    'overwrite': true,
    'prune': true,
    'version': '1.3.2',
    'version-string':{
      'CompanyName': 'Paulo Galdo',
      'FileDescription': 'Tierra de colores', /*This is what display windows on task manager, shortcut and process*/
      'OriginalFilename': 'TierraDesktop',
      'ProductName': 'Tierra de colores',
      'InternalName': 'TierraDesktop'
    }
};
packager(options, function done_callback(err, appPaths) {
    console.log(err);
    console.log(appPaths);
});
```

Comment: @JuliverGalleto This should be a script that you execute with node command line, 
`node file.js`

Answer (score 3):

```
electron-packager <sourcedir> <appname> --platform=<platform> --arch=<arch> [optional flags...]
```

> If appname is omitted, this will use the name specified by
>   "productName" or "name" in the nearest package.json.

Have you tried to set the 'name' property in package.json?

Comment: yeah, i've tried that too, same result. Also if i don't specify the app name on the consoleline throws me an error asking for electron-prebuilt as a dev dependency

Answer (score 1):

@Paulo Galdo Sandoval's answer is correct for `electron-packager`, but as of version `9.0.0` of the package, it automatically grabs information for those fields (`version-string` is now `win32metadata`). See the [release notes](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-packager/blob/master/NEWS.md) for that package

Answer (score 1):

You can change the app name in Electron Packager when you are building your Electron application for distribution. To do this, you can specify the `--appname` option during the packaging process.

```
electron-packager . YourAppName --platform=win32
```

By specifying the `--appname` option during packaging, you can change the name of your Electron app as it appears in the distribution package and other system-level views.

Answer (score 0):

electron-packager checks the output directory for an existing package based on the version name. If you did not change the version name when you tried to re-package with a different product name, electron-packager probably told you in the console that it was skipping the packaging process because a package already exists.