# Create Exe files using Electron without resource folder

Tags: angularjs, node.js, windows, electron

I have created a basic application in Electron (angular + Html + css + js). The app is working well and i tried to create a Exe file for different platform from windows.

First, I tried to create it for windows using the below script.

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "electron .",
    "build": "electron-packager . myApp --platform=win32 --arch=all"
  }
```

When I run it using the cmd **npm run build**, it creates a folder for both win 32 and 64 bit exe.

With in the folder, I found the **.exe** file with some dll files and a folder named 'resources' where i can find my application files.

How I should create exe file, so that it wont expose the code as i have to give my .exe file to different users to run in their systems.

Please let me know how to get exe without my app code included in the folder.

Comment: I can recommend you to use https://github.com/electron/windows-installer to make the whole installer once you have the folder with the files made of electron-packager. and leave you my example of using the API of electron packager http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38758444/electron-app-name-doesnt-change

Answer (score 2):

Electron is just a bundle of "interpreters" for your main and rendering processes written in javascript. 
There is no compiled binary file from your source code. 
But you can pack your source files into a `asar` archive, more info in [Electron documentation](http://electron.atom.io/docs/tutorial/application-distribution/).